# Create pyspark logic to populate columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes, one from today and one from yesterday and I need help to create a logic to compare them and create a new dataframe with the following columns:

`customer_id` -> Column used to compare

`person_id` -> Column used to compare

`type_person` -> If the type_person column is the same as the previous day keep it, if not update to the new status according to today.

`anterior_type` -> If the type_person column was updated, put the previous status here.

`update_date` -> Date the record was updated if there is a new type_person.

`create_date` -> Date the record was created.

Dataframe today:

| customer_id | person_id | type_person | insert_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4a5ae8a5-6682-467... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 1be8d3e8-8075-438... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 6912dadc-1692-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | e48cba37-113c-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 831cb669-b2ae-4e8... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 69161fe5-62ac-400... | Hybrid | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | b48b59a0-92eb-410... | Hybrid | 2022-03-03 |

Dataframe yesterday:

| customer_id | person_id | type_person | insert_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4a5ae8a5-6682-467... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | 1be8d3e8-8075-438... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | 6912dadc-1692-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | e48cba37-113c-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | 831cb669-b2ae-4e8... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | 69161fe5-62ac-400... | Online | 2022-03-02 |
| afabd2d2 | b48b59a0-92eb-410... | Online | 2022-03-02 |

In the case of today's dataframe I have 2 lines that changed to Hybrid, so they would have to have `update_date` and `anterior_type`, the others remain the same and with the other null fields in this dataframe.

Comment: Do you only look for modification or do you also track add/delete of the person?

Comment: @Emma I need to add new records and update old records if necessary, keeping the insertion date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweak the sample data to demonstrate the new record scenario. I added the last line.

| customer_id | person_id | type_person | insert_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4a5ae8a5-6682-467... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 1be8d3e8-8075-438... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 6912dadc-1692-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | e48cba37-113c-4bd... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 831cb669-b2ae-4e8... | Online | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | 69161fe5-62ac-400... | Hybrid | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | b48b59a0-92eb-410... | Hybrid | 2022-03-03 |
| afabd2d2 | xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx... | Online | 2022-03-03 |

To compare the difference, you can first join the 2 dataframes.

```py
# dft: today's dataframe, dfy: yesterday's dataframe
# If you also want to track the deletion, change how from left to outer.
df = dft.join(dfy, on=['customer_id', 'person_id'], how='left')
```

Then, use `when` to do the comparison.

```py
df = (df.withColumn('anterior_type', (F.when(dfy.type_person.isNull(), 'New')
                                       .when(dfy.type_person != dft.type_person, dfy.type_person)))
        .withColumn('update_date', F.when(dfy.type_person.isNull() | (dfy.type_person != dft.type_person), dft.insert_date))
```

Result

```
|customer_id|  person_id|type_person|insert_date|type_person|insert_date|anterior_type|update_date|
|-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|-------------+-----------|
|   afabd2d2|4a5ae8a5...|     Online| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|         null|       null|
|   afabd2d2|1be8d3e8...|     Online| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|         null|       null|
|   afabd2d2|6912dadc...|     Online| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|         null|       null|
|   afabd2d2|e48cba37...|     Online| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|         null|       null|
|   afabd2d2|831cb669...|     Online| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|         null|       null|
|   afabd2d2|69161fe5...|     Hybrid| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|       Online| 2022-03-03|
|   afabd2d2|b48b59a0...|     Hybrid| 2022-03-03|     Online| 2022-03-02|       Online| 2022-03-03|
|   afabd2d2|xxxxxxxx...|     Online| 2022-03-03|       null|       null|          New| 2022-03-03|
```

If you need a value other than `null` for `anterior_type` or `update_date`, you can chain `otherwise` after then `when` to add the value.